Uniqueness of Neumann series
Let $f$ be an entire function. Then there exist numbers $a_0,a_1,\ldots$, independent of $z$, such that
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n J_n(z),\quad \forall z\in\mathbb{C}$$
where $J_n$ is the Bessel function of the first kind of order $n$. This is called a Neumann series of $f$.
Question
Given $f$, are the numbers $a_n$ unique?
Thoughts
I took a look at Abramowitz and Stegun and Whittaker and Watson; in each book they mention the series but say nothing about the uniqueness of the coefficients. It would be nice if Neumann series turn out to be unique just as Taylor series of entire functions. I figured out that it is sufficient to prove that, for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$,

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n J_n(z)=0\implies \forall n\in\mathbb{N}:a_n=0;$$

Whittaker and Watson arrived at one possible integral representation of $a_n$ in terms of "Neumann polynomials". They essentially proved that if $a_n=\text{integral expression}$ then $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n J_n(z)$, not the other way around.
This question has also been asked on MSE as can be seen at this link. According to the user Conrad in the comments, the uniqueness is known if the Neumann series are required to be uniformly convergent, but not known if they're only pointwise convergent.
Edit:
I'm thinking about using "orthogonality", i.e.
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{J_{v+2l+1}(t)J_{v+2m+1}(t)}{t}\, dt=\frac{\delta_{l,m}}{2(2l+v+1)}$$
where $v+l+m\gt -1$
and then concluding that if $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n J_n (z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n J_n(z),$$
then
$$a_n=b_n$$
by the above orthogonality identity, but this requires me to justify switching $\sum_{n=0}^\infty$ with $\int_0^\infty.$
Please note that nothing about uniform convergence is assumed in this question; suppose that Neumann series only converge pointwise, nothing more.

As a side note, on the whole real line, the orthogonal relation for the ${J_n}{n\in\mathbb N}$ is somehow more complete because here $\int{\mathbb R}J_n(t)J_m(t)\frac1{|t|}dt=0$ also holds for every odd $n$ and  even $m$, since $J_n$ is an odd function and $J_m$ is an even function.

As I have been trying to point out in the comments to Pietro's answer: one can only use orthogonality if one specifies a particular inner product space; and entire functions do not belong to the completion of the system ${J_n}$ in $L^2({\mathbb R}, dx/|x|)$.

@Yemon even in a Hilbert space, pointwise convergence means nothing per se - the trigonometric series case shows - if $0=\sum c_ne^{inx}$ with pointwise convergence for all $x$, then yes we can say that $c_n=0$ but this is a highly nontrivial result (and one that doesn't hold if we just have a.e. convergence pointwise); if we have $\sum c_ne^{inx}$ converges in $L^2$ (and hence ae) then $c_n=0$ is a trivial result; here, on the other hand, pointwise convergence gives local uniform convergence on a large open set by analyticity and that is why I believe the solution is unique

(also, $J_k$ is not in the Hilbert space I mentioned for $k\le 0$)

@Conrad Indeed. I was just trying to point out why a lot of the discussion by other people here might be misdirected. People seem to be pointing out (basic) facts about orthogonal systems in Hilbert spaces without looking at the setting of the original question. (And yes, I am aware of Montel's theorem and related ideas)

Is this not evident from the fact that the Taylor expansion of $J_n(z)$ has lowest degree $n$? So (by induction) in order to make the $n$-th derivative of the sum vanish at $z=0$ the coefficient $a_n$ has to be zero too.

@KarlFabian No, it's not evident; I realized you have to prove absolute convergence in order to transform a Neumann series to a power series, so it's not that straightforward.

note that fixing some large $N$ (and using the existence of nontrivial entire functions that are bounded on any line in the plane - enough actually on any line that passes through the origin here) one can find a series of polynomials $Q_n, n \ge 1$ st $z^n | Q_n, n \le N, z^N | Q_n, n \ge N$ and $\sum_{n \ge 1}Q_n(z)=0$ pointwise for all $z$ but $\sum_{n \ge 1}(Q_n(z)/z)(0)=1$ while of course $\sum_{n \ge 1}(Q_n(z)/z)(w)=0, w \ne 0$ so algebraic arguments that include division by $z$ have to be treated carefully when the convergence is pointwise only

A more difficult question would be : if $\sum_n a_n J_n$ converge pointwise to $0$ on $\mathbb R$ are all coefficient zero?

Let me show that the convergence is uniform on balls, so that one can differentiate term by term and find the $a_n$ by evaluating at $z=0$, using that $J_n=c_nz^n+\dots$.
It is more convenient to use modified Bessel functions
$$I_n(z)=(-i)^nJ_n(iz)=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{1}{\Gamma(m+n+1)m!}\left (\frac{z}{2} \right)^{n+2m}.
$$
Then $f(iz)=\sum_{n} a_n J_n (iz)=\sum_n a_n i^n I_n(z)$.
Note that $I_n (1) \geq \frac{1}{n!2^n}$ and that $|I_n(z)| \leq \frac{1}{2^n n!}|z|^n e^{|z|^2/4}$.
Since the series converges at $x=1$ we get $|a_n| \leq Cn! 2^n$ and this gives uniform convergence on any ball or radius less than 1.

Great, you beat me on this. I was about to show from the series expansion  that for $x<2$ one has $J_{n+1}(x)/J_n(x) < \frac{x}{2,n}$, which also implies uniform convergence on sufficiently small intervals $[0,\epsilon]$.

Awesome! You're getting the bounty.

uh I didn't notice this answer, even more synthetic

edit: This was meant to recall a first elementary but relevant fact that was not mentioned at all, that is orthogonality.
Bessel functions $\{J_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N_+}$ are orthogonal on $\mathbb R$ w.r.to the measure $dx/|x|$. So existence and uniqueness of the expansion, in the corresponding Hilbert space, is just an instance of the well-known general fact [edit: that is the Fourier expansion of an element of a Hilbert space in a given orthonormal basis, here  the space spanned by the $J_n$'s].
[edit] in fact, since the degree of the lowest degree non-zero term of $J_n$ is $n$, the series makes sense even at the level of formal power series (for every sequence of coefficients), and you have uniqueness there (i.e. in  the broader sense), and existence ($a_n$ are determined inductively from an infinite triangular system).

What is the well-known general fact?

To use orthogonality, you need a Hilbert space to which every entire function belongs. What is this Hilbert space?

Note that I am claiming that uniqueness is not known if the series is pointwise convergent just that it requires a different proof than the simple proof when the series is locally uniformly convergent when $a_n$ is given by integrating on a small circle against $O_n$ the polynomials in $1/t$ defined inductively and orthogonal to $J_m, m \ne n$ as per the standard way of obtaining the expansion

Actually I was thinking that using Osgood theorem (pointwise convergence implies locally uniform convergent on a dense open set in the holomorphic case) may work though of course $0$ may not be in the open dense set from Osgood so one would need to use a circle not centered there where the convergence is uniform and integrate term by term against some related functions to $O_n$ and get $a_n$ that way

@AlexandreEremenko The Hilbert space here is just the closed subspace $V$ of $L^2(\mathbb R, dx/|x|)$ spanned by the ${J_n}_n$; this was a partial answer

@Nomas2 I was just referring to the existence and uniqueness of the Fourier expansion of an element of a Hilbert space in a given Hilbert bases. So uniqueness holds among expansion ${a_n}_n$ s.t. $\sum_n |a_n|^2|J_n|_2^2<\infty$, and existence for $f$ in the above mentioned space $V$. Sorry if all that was already obvious, but since no mention to orthogonality was done I though it was the case of make it. The italic was meant to suggest this is just a first order answer, and not complete.

(I was writing the answer  on a stoplight on my cell, then the green came and everybody behind started honking. Maybe some of them even downvoted)

Thank you very much for clarifying your answer. But where exactly do Fourier series come into play? Also, can you please point me to the relevant literature that is describing the uniqueness? I'm very new to all this, coming with a limited background.

Here, Fourier series of an element of an Hilbert space just means: expansion of x in an orthogonal basis ${e_n}$,  $x=\sum_n (x,e_n)e_n$ . For the general facts on Hilbert spaces see e.g. Rudin.

(I'm no expert of Bessel functions; I guess it should be well-known and classic what is the closed subspace of $L^2(\mathbb R, dx/|x|)$  generated by  ${J_n}{n\in\mathbb N}$, and also the space generated by ${J_n}{n\in\mathbb Z}$)

Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis (3rd ed.), Theorem 4.11a; is this the uniqueness theorem you're referring to?

Or is it Theorem 4.18(i)? I'm going to read the book and I need it for future reference.

(I mean the easy fact that: if ${e_n}n$ is an orthonormal basis and $x=\sum{n=0}^\infty x_ne_n$ (convergent series  in $H$),  then $x_n=(x,e_n)$, the Fourier coefficient of $x$ wrto $e_n$)

I'm still confused about something. Clearly the space in which the author's question is posed is not contained in $L^2({\mathbb R}, dx/|x|)$ since one is supposed to be able to represent any entire function as a pointwise-convergent infinite combination of the $J_n$. Perhaps the issue is that the reduction of the original "Question" to the statement about "if the sum of the series is zero, are all the terms zero" requires more justification?

@YemonChoi after reading your comment I realized that at least the uniqueness issue is just an algebraic fact in $\mathbb C[[z]]$ (added to the answer). I'm not able to answer the true questions though (like the one mentioned by A.Eremenko, and: what's the closed linear span of the $J_n$'s ; and: given f, in what sense does its formal series converge? Etc)

The projection-slice theorem may address some of the function space concerns.

@EricTowers I'm afraid that after looking at the link you give, I don't see the precise relevance. It certainly doesn't address my concerns

@Pietro Majer: This Hilbert space certainly does not contain ALL entire functions.

Consider a similar but simpler problem: every entire function can be expanded into a series of exponentials $e^{\lambda_k z}$ with some complex lambdas. But this expansion is not unique.

Yes, that is clear, there are entire functions that grow as fast as any increasing function for $t\to+\infty$...

I guess a first problem is clarifying in what sense the OP series is assumed to converge.  Here the simple sense is, as formal power series, and in this sense every $f$ has a unique expansion.

The example of exponentials ${e^{\lambda_k z}}$ is somehow more pathological because they all have complete power series at $0$,  whereas  $J_n(x)= \frac{x^n}{2^nn!}+$ higher order terms (So if the partial sums for $f$ converge in some even  weak sense that includes convergence of all derivatives at 0, e.g. $w-L^1$ locally at 0, the coefficient are determined)

@PietroMajer You say that I have to specify the sense in which my series converges. I thought the standard sense is the following: $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k$ converges if and only if for every $\epsilon\gt 0$, there is an $N$ such that for all $n\gt m\gt N$, we have $\left|\sum_{k=m+1}^n a_k\right|\lt \epsilon$. Is my question clear if I specify it like this? Would your answer differ in something?

I mean  in what sense   $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kJ_k$ converges to $f$ as a series of functions .  For instance, if  the partial sum converges  to $f$ uniformly in a (complex) nbd of 0,  or even $w-L^1_{loc}$, then  it also converges  coefficient-wise  (i.e.  as formal power series, so  the $a_k$  are those found equating the coefficients of both sides  of $f=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kJ_k$).  If  the series only converges point-wise, I’m not sure of what may happen.

@PietroMajer That's it. Nothing besides pointwise convergence is assumed.

@PietroMajer I thought $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n J_n(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_{n,k}z^{2k+n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_n b_{n,k}z^{2k+n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_{n,k}z^{2k+n}$; then why can't you say straightaway that $c_{n,k}$ are unique, hence $a_n$ are unique? Here, again, nothing besides pointwise convergence is assumed.

What I was saying is, I think it should be true here, thanks to  the special features of the $J_n$, but in general you could not  equating the coefficients of both sides just from the pointwise convergence; think of the example  mentioned by A.Eremenko with $e^{\lambda_nz}$ in place of $J_n$.

The pointwise convergence of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k e^{\lambda_kz}$  to $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty  f_nz^n$ does not allow you  expand the exponentials, reorder  the  double sum, and equating the coefficients.

@PietroMajer You need only absolute convergence to reorder the double sum. Can you please specify where exactly, in the equating coefficients process in A. Eremenko's example, do I need uniform convergence?

Exact, absolute convergence  (in your notations ,$\sum_{k,n}|c_{k,n}z^{2k+n}|<+\infty$) is  a very strong assumption.  It gives uniform  convergence  on compact sets of all derivatives,  and  in general would require strong bounds on the initial coefficients ${a_n}$ .

@PietroMajer Isn't the reason (why A. Eremenko's example fails) that we instead get $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n e^{\lambda_n z}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_{n,k}z^k$ where the coefficient of the lowest degree term is not $n$, unlike in the Bessel example?

Yep, that what I said.  The sequence of partial sums  $S_n(z):=\sum_{k=0}^na_kJ_k(z)$  has  the $k$-th degree coefficient that stabilises as soon as $n\ge k$, even for $f\in\mathbb C[[z]]$. This is  also what we mean saying  “$\sum_{k=0}^\infty f_kz^k =\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kJ_k(z)$  as formal power series .”

We can say a bit more: if a Neumann series converges point-wise, it also converges absolutely and in $\mathbb C[[z]]$, and the limit is an entire function.
Let $(a_n)_{n\ge0}$ be a sequence of complex numbers such that the Neumann series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n J_n(z)$$ converges point-wise on $\mathbb C$.   Let $z\in\mathbb C$ and $r:=|z|$. We have (by discrete Tonelli)
$$\sum_{k\ge0,\, n\ge0}  \Big|a_n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!(n+k)!}\big(\frac z2\big)^{n+2k}\Big|=\sum_{n\ge0}|a_n|  \sum_{k\ge0}\frac1{k!(n+k)!}\big(\frac r2\big)^{n+2k}.$$
The inner sum in $k$ writes
$$\sum_{k\ge0}\frac1{k!(n+k)!}\big(\frac r2\big)^{n+2k}= i^{-n}\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!(n+k)!}\big(\frac {ir}2\big)^{n+2k}=|J_n(ir)|\le\frac{|J_n(2ir)|}{2^n}. $$ By assumption, the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n J_n(2ir)$ is also convergent, so  $\big|a_n J_n(2ir)\big|\le M$ for some constant $M$. Then the above the double sum is majorized by
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\big|a_n J_n(2ir)\big|\frac1{2^n}\le \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac M{2^n}=2M<+\infty.$$
So  the family of terms   $\big\{a_n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!(n+k)!}\big(\frac z2\big)^{n+2k}: (n,k)\in\mathbb N^2\big\} $ is absolutely summable. Thus (by discrete Fubini) we can change order of summation and write $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n J_n(z) $ as a power series  of an entire function $f(z)$; moreover, as already observed, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n J_n(z) $ also converges in the sense of formal power series, and   $a_n$ are inductively determined by the coefficients of $f$ .

Thank you! Your answer helped me a lot as well. If only I could split the bounty between two people...

The first equation is suspicious, should it be inequality?

The double sum has an equality, because everything is non-negative

@Nomas2 It's fine, you did the right thing, and we are sportmen. Also thank you for the  interesting question
